# Validating input from user with QDialog PYTHON

Tags: python

I am trying to get the user to enter his/her name and it must contain only characters and max characters of 15. Here is my code, I have no idea how to do this

```
self.btn = QPushButton('Start', self)
    self.btn.move(20,20)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.btn)
    self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

def showDialog(self):
    text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog',
                                    'Enter your name:')

    if ok:
          self.theName.setText(str(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this  :

```py
def showDialog(self):
    text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog',
                                    'Enter your name:')

    if ok:
          if len(text)<=15 and text.isalpha() :  # Check if it contains 15 characters and only letters
               self.theName.setText(str(text))
               return
           else: 
              # Code when text is not correct
```